# jQuery closest does not return anything / does not find disabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create button which would enable the closest (above) input field.

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" disabled/>
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-input-activate" type="button">Change</button>
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.btn-input-activate').click(function () {
        var value = $(this).closest('input:disabled').val();
        alert("value is: " + value);
    });
}
```

I do not understand why this does not work (alert shows "value is: undefined").
I wanted to use `closest()` to avoid using multiple `parent()` methods on `$(this)`.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use one `parent` like so `var value = $(this).parent().prev().val();`

Comment: Using closest(): `$(this).closest(':has(input:disabled)').find('input:disabled').val();`  but quite sure, you **don't want** to use closest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misinterpreting what `closest()` does. It looks up the DOM tree for ancestors.

Your input is not an ancestor of the button. It is a sibling of the button's parent

Try

```
 $(this).closest('span').siblings('input:disabled').val();
```

OR

```
$(this).parent().siblings('input:disabled').val();
```

Reference: [closest() api docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)